# How can I kill a detached thread I have made in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a c++ class where in one of its functions I start the following thread?

```
std::thread([&](){ funk(); }).detach();
```

which runs another function of this class (func) in a thread. How can I stop or kill this thread only without killing the whole application?

Comment: It would help if you retained a reference to it. Otherwise you're throwing away the key.

Comment: @tadman  I'm a bit new to c++, not sure what you mean by key, or why not throw it away, and how to retain a reference to it.

Comment: I'm positive you can't. You are explicitly telling the program you aren't interested in controlling this thread. Why `detach` it at all, why not just maintain a reference to it?

Comment: What I mean is the only way to control this thread is to retain some information about it, in other words the "key" to using it. What you're doing is like saying "I ran a function, didn't capture the output, but I want the output, so how do I get it back?" You can't. You need to save the output in a variable or you've missed your chance.

Comment: @Tas wouldn't cause any interruption in the main application if I don't detach it?

Comment: A) Why are you detaching the thread? B) Why do you need to control it after detaching? Usually you detach when you want it to run independently, from that point forward.

Comment: You could give your thread a messaging facility (e.g. a channel or some message queue...) and then send a message via that queue. Or keep a reference to the thread instance. Depends on your use cases and design.

Comment: @tadman I just thought if I have it detached it is less likely that it cause intrupption of the main thread, or the main application interrupt the functionality inside it. the "func" has a loop in it running at 1KHz

Comment: Threads don't interrupt other threads unless there's some explicit code to do so. The operating system handles thread scheduling, not your app.

Comment: Even if you have the `thread` object there isn't much you can do to stop it. The best way to end a thread is to ask it to end, pass it a message or set a flag usually. Killing a thread outright can lead to unstable programs.

Comment: Show more code context.

Comment: @tadman how do I change my line of code so that I don't detach it and also be able to stop it.

Comment: `std::thread mythread([&](){ funk(); }).`. Now you store `mythread` somewhere safe and long-enough lived to last until you need it again.

Comment: Just store it in a variable, easy.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks, and how do I tell it to stop?

Comment: `mythread.join();` waits until the thread ends. If you want to manually end the thread, you can't. Not with a `thread` member function call.  You have to do something smarter. And to know what that smarter is, or if it's even possible, we need more information about how you're using the thread..

Comment: @user4581301 so this thread actually never ends, it just has a while loop inside it for doing some computation at 1000-Hertz,

Comment: @Azerila my go to idiom is a stop flag. Have `funk()` take a reference to some `std::atomic_flag`, and maintain a handle on that. Make the while loop exit when this flag is set to `true` (or `false` depending on what you name it). I've used `kill_me`, `keep_working`, and `stop_flag` as names for this usually. C++20 has `stop_token` which seems similar, but may have additional functionality I'm not aware of.

Comment: Have the thread check an an atomic flag variable ([`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag), maybe) at the start of every cycle and exit the thread loop when it's true (or false if [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) thinks it makes better sense). In the main thread, or whatever's controlling the other thread, you set the flag and maybe `join` and wait for it to finish. Maybe `detach` and assume it finishes. May want a timer to guard on it if you `join` so you don't block forever if the thread's locked up.

Comment: Forget join. Set terminate flag,  set priority to lowest and just ignore it until it dies.

Answer (score 3):

In c++ there is no way to simply terminate a thread from another thread. And for good reasons. A thread might have acquired some resources (handles, memory, locks, etc...) and there is no generic way of releasing those resources. Only the thread itself knows how to. Therefore, introducing a way to enable a thread to terminate another thread is not helpful, if not dangerous and cause of software bugs.

As others pointed out in comments, a good way of doing this is to pass a reference to a flag that is essentially a way to "message" the thread to terminate. This assumes that a long running thread operates a in a `while` loop. To terminate the thread it must `break` out of that loop. The condition to `break` is the aforementioned flag. After the while loop, the thread's code will do any necessary clean up and return form the thread's main function which ends the thread.

That being said, you must write your thread function to be "cancel friendly". It should have some loop in the first place in order to be broken. or call functions that accept a cancel flag reference.

So not all operation are cancelable or at least "immediately" cancelable. You have probably seen long running operations that when you click on "cancel" it takes a few second to actually cancel. You might have wondered why would canceling something takes so much time. I did. Well, here is the reason.

Comment: After setting the stop flag, setting the thread priority to the lowest available will reduce its influence until it gets round to terminating itself.